# how compile wxwidget 3.1 with tdm gcc 5.1 ? version 64bit on i5 windows 7 64biti and use on codebloks 16?

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw

I was using this for compiling

> mingw32-make -j4 -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release CXXFLAGS="-fno-keep-inline-dllexport -std=c++11" MONOLITHIC=1

or

> mingw32-make -f makefile.gcc SHARED=1 UNICODE=1 BUILD=release MONOLITHIC=1

with `wxwidget`  3.1 /3.0 /3.0.1 /3.0.2  mising lib `lwxmsw3xx` or I get error on compiling process with tdm gcc 4.8 to 5.1 , mingw gcc 4.9.3 to mingw-w64 gcc 6 dragon.

I succeeded compiling and use wxwidget 2.8.12 but when I start coding surprise not support c++11 . on 3.1 missing lib or dll or I get error gcc 4.8 to 6

Comment: ||=== Build: Release in aaaaaaac (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
ld.exe||cannot find -lwxmsw30u|
||error: ld returned 1 exit status|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|

Answer (score -1, accepted):

problem solved rename file -lwxmsw31u   to   -lwxmsw30u and every thing work like charm , the problem was i think from codeblocks it's not suport 3.1.0

Comment: You shouldn't leave your reader in confusion. Give clear explanation.

Comment: why ? you are lost? i did that and he worked. (read  above before complaining or vote)